# filecoordinationd is blocking my Trash from emptying it

Tags: macos, trash

I've got a fresh M2 MacBook Pro which I configured as new (not a backup restore).

Very often, when I try emptying the Trash, the process hangs waiting for something.

When I then do

```sh
sudo lsof +c0 .Trash
```

I get the following:

```
COMMAND           PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
filecoordinationd 609 root   14r   DIR   1,15      416 276911 .Trash
```

When I then subsequently run

```sh
sudo killall -9 filecoordinationd
```

the trash emptying process unblocks and finishes successfully.

I encounter this from time to time, throughout machine restarts.

Does anyone knows what's happening or how to debug this?